# How to build progress bar with circle at the end of bar?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I need to build horizontal progress bar with circle at the end in react js, as shown in picture. I am able to build progress bar with custom "%", now I want to add circle at the end with some text inside.

[image: progress bar with circle]

code for progress bar with custom "%":
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-meninsky-sd70l?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I can't see any code in your sandbox, did you save it?

Comment: Can you please check once again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change progress bar component to:

```
  <div style={containerStyles}>
      <div style={fillerStyles}>
        <div style={circleStyles}>{circleText}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And add this styles to the component:

```
  const circleStyles = {
    display: "flex",
    position: "absolute",
    right: "0",
    width: "50px",
    height: "50px",
    background: "blue",
    top: "-60%",
    borderRadius: "50px",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    color: "white"
  };
```

And here's the `App.js`:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ProgressBar
        bgcolor={item.bgcolor}
        completed={item.completed}
        circleText={"100%"}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit objective-cherry-2ytzm]

Answer (score 0):

add a span under container div and put this style to it

```
<div style={containerStyles}>
  <div style={fillerStyles}></div>
  <span style={circleStyle}>{text}</span>
</div>
```

style

```
const circleStyle = {
  height: 40,
  width: 40,
  position: "absolute",
  right: 0,
  backgroundColor: bgcolor,
  borderRadius: "50%",
  top: -10,
  display: "flex",
  alignItems: "center",
  justifyContent: "center",
  color: "white"
};
```

and then put this to containerStyle

```
position: "relative",
```